# Setting up cross-store coupons

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, coupon

I have two stores. We need to have all registered users of store A be given a coupon code (either upon checkout or account creation) that is valid for Store B.

These stores are not on the same magento installation. Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can any visitor use this coupon?  Or only registered customers from the store A?

Answer (score 1):

### Offline

Create a lot coupons in Store B put them somehow into your store A and send them from there.

### Online

Implement API/SOAP/REST in Store B, request code from store b so you can send them per mail

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/coupon-import-export-1.html) is free extension which will allow you to import/export coupon information. Try it maybe it will help you.

Comment: Not sure if the free module will work for CE 1.9 based on it's compatibility information.